# Jquery Page Change Without Flashing Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I achieve a page load without the flash of the content. I have a calendar and while changing months I can get the top bar to stay when pages are changed (using sammy.js) but when I change months the content flashes and it looks ugly. I've tried fading in and out but can't get it to look good. Would a loading image be the way to go? If so, how would that be done, I'm fairly new to jquery.

Right now my code is

```
 this.get('#/calendar/:month/:year', function(context) {
              context.app.swap('');
              context.$element().fadeOut('slow');
              context.$element().load('calshow.php?m=' + this.params['month'] +'&y=' + this.params['year'] +'');
              context.$element().fadeIn('slow');
                       });
```

Thanks in advance for any help, I'm stumped!

Answer (score 1):

shot in the dark guess

try this

```
this.get('#/calendar/:month/:year', function(context) {
              var $currentElement = context.$element();

              context.app.swap('');
              $currentElement.fadeOut('slow', function(){
                  $currentElement.load('calshow.php?m=' + this.params['month'] +'&y=' + this.params['year'] +'', function(){
                      $currentElement.fadeIn('slow');
                  });
              });
```

EDIT: edited the example.  The fadeOut method has an oncomplete method.  this might work better for you.

Edited Again: found that the load method also has a oncomplete method.  I dont like chaining onCompletes like this but it might work for you.  I also created a variable for the context.$element().  I found that helps when you're chaining stuff like this together.

let me know how it works out

Comment: Has the same effect as my code above. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: by looking at the example i think you want to fade out, load the data, then fade in, but instead its loading the data before the jquery transition fades out completely... let me look into this and come back to it

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I want to do, but jquery is fairly new to me so I don't know exactly how to get it accomplished haha. But awesome, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried putting the `fadeIn` in the `load` [complete callback](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?

Comment: Kenneth Garza, I tried that earlier and it won't load the content then, I don't know if it's a conflict with sammy js or what, shoot!
@Owlvark yeah, I tried that

Comment: ok, check out this fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/F7g92/ Its based on what you're trying to do.  The method I sent you is the correct way of doing what you want to do.  Why it isnt loading is another issue and i dont think has anything to do with this.  I did notice that if I put some break points on your code that it didnt work right.  I am not a huge fan of the use of .load() as it seems to me to be just a bit of a pain.  But thats my opinion.

Comment: Your fiddle works like a charm but then I put it in my code and it fails me. It must be clashing with a plugin of mine or something, maybe i'll just have to find an alternate way of doing this. Thanks very much for the time you've invested into helping, though!

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.get('#/calendar/:month/:year', function(context) {
      context.app.swap('-Have to put text here to fill empty space-').effect('fold');
      context.$element().load('calshow.php?m=' + this.params['month'] +'&y=' + this.params['year'] +'');
      context.$element().show('');
```

I was messing around with it and this code seems to work pretty nice for what I want it to do. It still is pretty much the same, the fancy effects just disguise the "flash" of it.

Comment: ok, just make sure you test this in all major browsers.  Different browsers (IE for example) dont do these transitions in the exact same way and while it may work in chrome, it will not in IE or firefox.  Not to say this will not work in all browsers, just a tip for testing.   Hope this works out for you, additionally, i updated my example earlier with a new approach, you might want to try that if this doesnt work out for you.

Comment: Yeah I gave it a test in all of them and it even surprisingly works in IE (Usually I just skip coding for IE because, so this is convenient!)  I think this is what I'll go with, it gives it a neat effect and makes it look pretty modern. Also, your other method didn't work either, I think it must conflicting with sammyjs. Thank you very much anyway, though!